# how to disable angular material typography styles?

Tags: angular, angular-material

how to disable angular material typography styles after installed angular materials? It is changing my visual style and it is not easy to overwrite. I dont need it, just need to get rid of it.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Inside your index.html file, the body tag should have `class="mat-typography"`, just remove this class and your styles shouldn't be overwritten anymore. You should also check if your Angular Material theme doesn't contain any custom typography like it's shown in Typography guide (https://material.angular.io/guide/typography)

Comment: Sure wish it was this easy, I've removed this from my index.html and it works for ng serve but on production build it's still inheriting the styles somehow.. and I cleared cache/etc.  (angular 11)

Answer (score 2):

**Change below things in index.html file**

- Remove all stylesheet links related to material.
- Then remove class="mat-typography" from body